# Reading Excel file with sheets in hadoop Map reduce

Tags: hadoop

I am having an excel file which contains around 20 sheets in a single file.
I want to read it through map reduce program in hadoop.can anyone help me to solve this.
Please suggest that how can i read it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried through POI but it is reading single sheet, but i want to read complete 20 sheets in the excel file, please suggest....

Answer (score 0):

You may find that the [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) library can be used in your mappers to parse your Excel files.